# How to compare dates for multiple rows under the same table and same account

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, compare, report

If any SQL gurus could point me in the right direction on this would be a huge help. I'm learning SQL and want to create a report that would generate the Account #s under the *same* Person ID that were created <= 30 days of each other and exclude any others. All the information needed is in the same table.

For example this code pulls up a list of Person's with the same personid who have more than one Accountid and their Creation date:

```
    select accounttid, creationdate, personid from Table1 where personid in ( 
    select (personid) from Table1 group by personid having COUNT (accountid) > 1)


EXAMPLE RESULT:
    accountid   creationdate    personid
    5501624 2013-05-01  101
    5501544 2013-05-03  101
    5510220 2013-10-24  10337
    5504204 2013-06-27  10337
    5502332 2013-05-21  1047
    5502628 2013-05-28  1047
    5508844 2013-10-01  1047
```

Not sure where to go from here. I want to then take these Accountids and somehow compare the Creationdates for less than or equal to a 30 day differential but only compare them when the PersonIDs are the same.

Comment: What do you exactly mean by `Account #s .... that were created <= 30 days of each other` ? Say there are 4 accounts (under the same person), first account created at `2013-01-30`, second at `2013-02-28`, thid one at `2013-03-25` and fourth at `2013-04-15`. We can say that they all are `<=30 days of each other`, which records do you want to get ? All of them, or first two records from january + february, or maybe two last records from march+april ?

Comment: Yes I would need to return all four of those account #s since each one is within 30 days of another one. For instance in your example say there's 5 accounts and the 5th one was created on 2013-06-01 the script should return the first 4 but omit the last one because it's not within 30days of another one. And of course these would all be under the same PersonID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a semi join:

```
select accountid, creationdate, personid 
from Table1 t1
where EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t2
  WHERE t1.personid = t2.personid
    AND t1.accountid <> t2.accountid
    AND t1.creationdate BETWEEN
           t2.creationdate - interval 30 day
        AND
           t2.creationdate + interval 30 day
);
```

demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2be93/2

**--- EDIT ---**

---

On SQL-Server use this condition:

```
 BETWEEN dateadd( day, -30, t2.creationdate )
     AND
         dateadd( day, 30, t2.creationdate )
```

here is a query for SQL-Server:

```
select accountid, creationdate, personid 
from Table1 t1
where EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t2
  WHERE t1.personid = t2.personid
    AND t1.accountid <> t2.accountid
    AND t1.creationdate BETWEEN
           dateadd( day, -30, t2.creationdate )
        AND
           dateadd( day, 30, t2.creationdate )
);
```

demo: ----> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/cc922/4

---

Some remark to your query:

```
select accountid, creationdate, personid 
from Table1 
where personid in ( 
    select personid 
    from Table1 
    group by personid 
    having COUNT(accountid) > 1
);
```

think a while ..... the subquery with `HAVING COUNT` must calculate a number of records for each person - it must read the whole table (all rows) to obtain this information, because we asked `give me a number of rows for given person`. If this person has 10.000 accounts, we need read all of them to count them.
However, we don't need this information and we don't need to read the whole table. What we need is the answer for this question: `if this person has at least 2 accounts`.
For this kind of queries we can use an `EXISTS` operator:

```
select accountid, creationdate, personid 
from Table1 t1
where EXISTS(
  SELECT 1 FROM Table1 t2
  WHERE t1.personid = t2.personid
    AND t1.accountid <> t2.accountid
);
```

In this query MySql doesn't need to count all records and doesn't need to read a whole table. It stops reading the table when it finds first record that meets criteria defined by the subquery inside EXISTS operator.

Comment: Hi Kordirko, for some reason "interval" is giving me an error "invalid column name". I replaced your "between" statement with "AND DateDIFF(day, b.creationdate, a.creationdate) <= 30)" which seems to work but I'm still getting accountids that aren't within 30 days of another. I'm just finding out that the creationdate field isn't a "datetime" data type field. It's a nvarchar field. Could that be causing the issue? Also your script obtains less results than @blam 's. BTW thanks for all your effort here. It is truly appreciated and I can't wait until I'm knowledgeable enough to help others!

Comment: I'm on SQL Server 2008

Comment: On SQL Server use `BETWEEN dateadd( day, -30, t2.creationdate ) AND dateadd( day, 30, t2.creationdate )`, I have added a query with a demo for SQL-Server in my answer. Please also change tag from `mysql` to `sql-server` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct(personid, accountID)
  from Table1 
 where Table1 personid in 
       ( 
        select distinct(t1a.personid)
          from Table1 as t1a 
          join Table1 as t1b
            on t1a.personid = t1b.personid
           and t1a.creationdate < t1b.creationdate
           and datediff(dd, t1a.creationdate, t1b.creationdate) <= 30
       )
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Unfortunately this did not work. I changed your first line to "select distinct(t1a.accountid)" as I need those instead of the personids but for some reason this is pulling personids/accountids were there is only one accountID under that personid. If there aren't multiple accountIDs under a personID they should be omitted from the results. If there is more than one accountID under a particular PersonID then the creationdate should be compared for equal to or less than 30 days of each other. If they are then list those specific AccountIDs.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can join the result that you have got to itself based on the condition that `personid` should be same and the difference between two `creationdate`s is greater than 30 days.

Something like:

```
{select accounttid, creationdate, personid 
 from Table1 where personid in ( 
    select (personid) 
    from Table1 
    group by personid 
    having COUNT (accountid) > 1)} as a 
join 
{select accounttid, creationdate, personid from 
 Table1 where personid in ( 
    select (personid) from 
    Table1 
    group by personid 
    having COUNT (accountid) > 1)} as b 
on a.personid=b.personid and a.creationdate-b.creationdate >= 30
```